# Unique Sub-site Permission Groups

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, groups

So after searching all over google and bing, I think I've come to an answer that I don't really want to hear, but there's no harm in asking here :). Is it possible to have unique permissions for a group that exists in both a parent and sub-site that has had its inheritance broken? Ex: Parent site has an owners group with John, Jake, and Sam. Sub-site has unique permissions and the same owners group but with Sarah, James and Nancy instead.

My initial thought when I was asked about this was to just create new groups in the sub-site with the appropriate users, but that was before I realized there are 100+ groups each with multiple users and six sub-sites that I would need to recreate them for. Is there any other way to achieve this, it would be a HUGE pain to have to recreate all the groups with the appropriate users for every single sub site.

Thanks,

David

Comment: Is the following correct: You want to have 1 group that has different members in different (sub)sites?

Comment: Yea, pretty much

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create the various groups more then once. Create those groups at the root level and assign them a permission level, perhaps even limitted access if they are not supposed to access anything at all at the root level. Then create the sub sites, break the permissions, and reassign the permission level of the relevant groups.

Comment: What's the difference between doing that and just creating new groups at the subsite? Either way I'd have to create new groups for various members (some of which might overlap)  with varying permission levels

Comment: Not much, except in the odd case where you are able to reuse an existing group. It might also be easier maintanencewise when Bob should be a members of the same groups as Alice

Comment: Honestly, I think that's what I'm going to end up doing because logically, I can't think of any other way. But is there anyway to do it without having to create any new groups at all?

Comment: Do you have an AD group for each of those groups ( if you coming from  file shares and ACLs)?

Comment: No, there isn't any AD groups for any of these. They are straight SharePoint permission groups